# Getting 'Invalid hook call' when button is clicked on react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to make the button work when it is clicked. I want it to print out incorrect or correct when the answer to the question is right or wrong. I have a user-defined component, where I am defining the button. I don't know where my code is messed up, as I am receiving the 'invalid hook call' error when I click the button to see if I am wrong or right.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert, ScrollView, Image, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
function Question(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Text>{props.text}</Text>
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        style={{ height: 40, borderWidth: 1, padding: 20, paddingTop: 10, margin: 5 }}
        editable
        maxLength={40} />
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Button onPress={props.onPress}
          title="check"
          color="#841584" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={props.style}>{props.answerX}</Text>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const [UserAnswer1, setUserAnswer1] = useState('');
 
  const [rightWrong1, setRightWrong1] = useState('');

  const [store1, storeAns1] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (UserAnswer1 === 'Yes' || UserAnswer1 === 'yes' || UserAnswer1 === 'YES' ) {
      storeAns1('Correct');
    }
    else if (UserAnswer1 === 'No' || UserAnswer1 === 'no' || UserAnswer1 === 'NO') {
      storeAns1('Incorrect');
    } 

  }, [store1])

  const ans1=()=>{
    setRightWrong1(store1);
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.title1}>Quiz Time</Text>

        <Image source={require('./images/pic.jpeg')} style={styles.uriImg} />

        <View>
          <Question text='Is this Mt. Fuji? (Yes/No)'
          multiline
            numberOfLines={4}
            value={UserAnswer1}
            onChangeText={ansText1 => setUserAnswer1(ansText1)}
            answerX={rightWrong1}
            onPress={ans1}
          /></View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect the outcome to be from `<Button onPress={useEffect}`?

Comment: I think maybe you mean to put `<Button onPress={props.onPress}`

Comment: @BrianThompson Sorry, that is a typo. I was trying to do a bunch of things to make it work. But it shouldn't be there, my bad. I'll edit it out. Also, i tried what you said, but the button the incorrect/correct doesn't show on the app.

Comment: I think your `useEffect` dependencies are causing the problem. You need it to run when `UserAnswer1` changes, not `store1`. At least thats how I interpret it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!